# Laravel 5.2 session is back to live after Auth::logout()

Tags: laravel-5

I have a Login controller wich manages my login/logouts and it has 2 methods:

```
public function login(Request $request){        
    if($request->has('email') && $request->has('password')){
        if(Auth::check())
            Auth::logout();
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password')])){                
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.index');
        }
        else{

            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

    return redirect('/');
}

public function logout(){
    Auth::logout();
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::flush();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

So, when I login it redirects to the dashboard, now, when I logout it redirects to home, here I run Auth::check() if true go to dashboard if not stay at home so, in my case stays at home so session was destroyed, but here is the issue, if I reload the page right from there, the session is alive again therefore i'm redirected to dashboard

Why session is apparently destroyed in the first try and then comes back alive again?

Comment: Try `$this->logout()` instead of `Auth::logout()` in `login` function and see does it makes any change

Comment: And use `use Session;` then there will be no need of `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::flush();` just use `Session::flush();` instead.